# how to maintain the image aspect ratio in bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to use the bootstrap carousel and started with example as shown here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

I have loaded test jpg (1200x480) into slides, but when you resize the browser, the images are shortened in the horizontal direction while maintaining the vertical size resulting in an increasingly distorted image as the browser is made smaller.

I've searched and found others with the same issue or some similar issue but no one has suggested anything that actually works.

Does anyone have a solution for maintaining the image aspect ratio for jpg in the bootstrap carousel?

Comment: did my solution worked for u?

Answer (score 1):

you can resize the height of your carousel using css. this worked for me:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

you can use @media to get the windowsize and set cssrules for each width using:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { }

@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1000px) { }

@media (min-width: 1001px) { }
```

possibly you have to use it for your image-size, too.

Comment: you have to set height to .caroussel selector on each rule, also.